I want to use the flutter icon but why it does not shown?
[1]this is my page the navigation bar and the like button should show icon but it does not
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
// import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());// run from here
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { //myapp ni main coding die
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build = what this widget contain
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(//material of the app
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true, //material3 tu design
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 34, 233)),
          // textTheme: GoogleFonts.lobsterTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: NavigationRail(
              extended: false,
              destinations: [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: Text('Home'),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  label: Text('Favorites'),
                ),
              ],
              selectedIndex: 0,
              onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                print('selected: $value');
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
              child: GeneratorPage(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

this is my pubspec.yml
this is my first coding in flutter . when hovering my cursor on the Icons.favourite the icons appear but when i debug the icon does not appear. do i need to change something in my pubspec.yml or are there something wrong my code.
my navigationrail

Hi Muqri, can you also share a snippet of your  NavigationRailDestination widget?

What icon are you referring to? The provided code does not seem to have an icon widget...

aint "icon: Icon(Icons.home)"  refer to the use of the home icon

already update the navigationrail widhet

in pubspec.yaml in dependencies section
add :   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6


already added but the icon still not appear
